# fetch Data from a server

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I need a simple function in objective C to get data from a webserver, something like the php function `file_get_contents`, I dont need to submit any POST data so its gona be simple.

Thanks

Comment: I never said its a free code shop!! its a site where programmers help each other out and thats what I am asking for. I have a very long function atm that sends the to the page perfectly fine, but I was hoping there was like a simple one line code that I could use (like in php you `wget`, `file_get_contents` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends a bit on the contents of the data you want to retrieve. As an example, if the data can be interpreted as a UTF8-encoded string you could use:

```
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

If you just want to get bytes of data without interpreting as a string you can also do this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

You then have all the data available to parse out however you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The NSData class has a method 'dataWithContentsOfURL' that will enable you to retrieve data from a webserver.

Sample code:

```
NSData* someData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:someURL]];
```

Official documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html